# simple loading data using datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm trying to load the data using the datatables but when I run this page it shows `processing` does not give any error.

```
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../html/content/css/app.css">
  <script src="../../html/content/js/library/jquery.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#data').dataTable({
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "http://api.geonames.org/countryInfoJSON?username=design1online",
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <div class="widget-gridview">
      <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" id="data" width="100%">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th style="width:6em"> continent</th>
            <th> capital</th>
            <th style="width:6em"> languages</th>
            <th style="width:4em"> population</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr class="odd">
            <td width="140"> </td>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot></tfoot>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You need to look in the developer tools of you browser and see if it gives any additional information

Comment: I'm using chrome and I do not see any errors in the console

Comment: Have you looked at the response body to see if it is the JSON you are expecting

Comment: yes I do see the JSON data and I have created jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/abuhamzah/hzh1e0q0/

Answer (score 0):

[image]Suggestion:

1. including dataTable js and css files
2. From debug console, there is an error message "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"
3. There are 17 properties in each record, but you only have 4 td for each row in your html code.
4. Here is one of your data record.

   "continent":"EU",
   "capital":"Andorra la Vella",
   "languages":"ca",
   "geonameId":3041565,
   "south":42.42849259876837,
   "isoAlpha3":"AND",
   "north":42.65604389629997,
   "fipsCode":"AN",
   "population":"84000",
   "east":1.7865427778319827,
   "isoNumeric":"020",
   "areaInSqKm":"468.0",
   "countryCode":"AD",
   "west":1.4071867141112762,
   "countryName":"Andorra",
   "continentName":"Europe"
   "currencyCode":"EUR"

Comment: I do have datatable.js included in the external resource....the reason I did not add all 17 properties because I do not want to have clutter on the page even though why would that matter? I can have one or all, I do not think that will make any difference but thanks for looking into it.

Answer (score 0):

JSON is not valid:

```
Parse error on line 1212:
...: "EU",            "
----------------------^
Expecting 'STRING'
```